# API Leaflet. Меню

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Как сделать такое меню. Никак не получаеться, возможно что-то упускаю.

[image: Карта]

```js
var cities = L.layerGroup();

L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
  L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
  L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
  L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);


var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
  '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
  'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
    id: 'mapbox.light',
    attribution: mbAttr
  }),
  streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    attribution: mbAttr
  });

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [39.73, -104.99],
  zoom: 10,
  layers: [grayscale, cities]
});

var baseLayers = {
  "Grayscale": grayscale,
  "Streets": streets
};

var overlays = {
  "Cities": cities
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

//Create Menu
var drawControl = global.drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
    edit: {
      selectedPathOptions: {
        maintainColor: true,
        moveMarkers: true
      }
    }
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'marker') {
    layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
  }

  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

var toolbar = global.toolbar = (function() {
  for (var type in drawControl._toolbars) {
    if (drawControl._toolbars[type] instanceof L.EditToolbar) {
      return drawControl._toolbars[type];
    }
  }
})();

toolbar._modes.edit.handler.enable();

L.DomEvent.on(document.querySelector('.centroids'), 'change', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //if (e.target.checked) {
    L.EditToolbar.Edit.MOVE_MARKERS = e.target.checked;
    toolbar._modes.edit.handler.disable();
    toolbar._modes.edit.handler.enable();
    //}
  }, 50);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ты в консоль-то смотрел? global не определён, drawnItems не определён...

Comment: Как бы такое меню как показано на скрине формируется с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman